# Открыть внешнее приложение внутри своего. C++, Qt

Tags: c++, windows, qt, winapi, exec

Я бы хотел открывать windows приложения внутри своего, для примера можно взять тот же калькулятор или блокнот. Насколько я помню, я запускал приложение, а после, по хэндлу окна, пытался перенести его внутрь моего. В итоге я просто куда-то терял окно приложения, но при этом процесс оставался в памяти. Использовал я `createWindowContainer`, если не ошибаюсь. Если можно, хотелось бы увидеть минимальный рабочий пример запуска калькулятора внутри своего Qt приложения.

Answer (score -1):

Используйте `QX11EmbedContainer`.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    if (app.arguments().count() != 2) {
        qFatal("Error - expected executable path as argument");
        return 1;
    }

    QX11EmbedContainer container;
    container.show();

    QProcess process(&container);
    QString executable(app.arguments()[1]);
    QStringList arguments;
    arguments << QString::number(container.winId());
    process.start(executable, arguments);

    int status = app.exec();
    process.close();
    return status;
}
```

Comment: ох, не уверен я, что оно под виндой заработает

Comment: @KoVadim, я уже год не пользуюсь Windows. Qt мне это позволяет.

Comment: это хорошо, но автор вопроса спрашивает о windows, а не xwindows.

Comment: У меня Qt 5.6, стоило уточнить, прошу прощения, из него убрали QX11EmbedContainer

Comment: @МишаковМаксим Попробуйте   http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#createWindowContainer , http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwindow.html#fromWinId .